# Upset about not being able to ask questions

Tags: discussion

So someone answered my question and another person thought it was stupid and gave me a -1. Is that a reason to ban me from asking anymore questions? Because one person thought my question was not necessary even though someone else answered it?

I am really upset about that system, I ask questions only after about an hour of googling and not finding the answer.

Comment: You have asked 10 questions (2 deleted now). None of which got a single upvote. That should tell you something.

Comment: @Oded it tells me that no one likes the questions, but they don't exist on the website, which means that even though no one likes them they are new.

Comment: New doesn't mean they are of the high quality we seek. That they still exist may simply mean that they haven't been seen by enough people to get removed.

Comment: @Oded sure sure. Well are there any other websites that accept "non-experienced" questions like mine?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/839601)

Comment: @Gnat read Oded's answer. If the question doesn't have the answer that's not their problem, they want "Qualtiy" questions

Comment: This is not about "non-experienced". We don't have a problem with that. We do have a problem with questions that don't show your efforts or that are unsuitable to the site (as described in our [help/on-topic]).

Answer (score 19):

Let me put [Oded's point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275477/upset-about-not-being-able-to-ask-questions#comment111033_275477) in a different way...

Imagine yourself as a senior developer leading a team.  One of the brand new hires walks over to your office and asks you what is the Regex for matching a number.  Maybe you are feeling charitable and you give him the answer and go back to work.

Now imagine that new hire comes back to your desk 5 minutes later and says that Regex isn't working but provides no other details.  So in order to solve his problem, you need to get up and walk over to his desk and look at his debugger to see why it isn't working.

And then he starts coming back to your desk every 15 minutes with a new problem, but fails to show he is making even the slightest effort to solve the problem himself before coming to you.

How would you feel after the 3rd or 4th interruption?  Would you tell him to stop coming in until he asked better questions?

---

Think of asking a question on Stack Overflow as asking your senior developer for help.

- You don't really want to bother him/her unless you absolutely need to do it.
- And when you do, you want to show him/her that you have indeed tried to solve the problem yourself.
- And you want to provide him as much relevant information as possible in order to help him solve your problem without walking over to your desk.

This is why you were question banned.  You kept walking over to your senior's desk and he finally told you to stop bugging him until you learn to ask better questions.

It's not about how basic or how complicated the question is.  It is about the quality of the question.  Did you completely explain the problem?  Did you provide all of the relevant information, such as error messages, the input values, the expected output, what output you were getting?  If you have code, did you provide a **short** snippet that reproduces the problem?

The way you earn your way back into good graces is you go back and tried to fix your past questions.  Make them better, you will get some upvotes and you will eventually be able to ask again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was much more respectable than Oded's. I do already have that in mind, and I do not ask my question unless I have spent at least one hour googling before and I have absolutely no other option, besides one of my questions was to the support of fineuploader who monitor the tag.

Comment: Just because some external body uses SO for support doesn't excuse poor questions.

Comment: Only *one* hour on Google? I've learned new languages and data formats, just to check if a question was a good one.

Comment: @user3509585: The time to google isn't the problem I guess, take the time to create a good and complete question.

Comment: Kudos for presenting the same old story in a very innovative and novel style. Wonderfully written post.